# select the random image id every 24 hours

Tags: java, android

I want to select an image id every 24 hours . for example at special time like 12 a.m , i able to select a random id to set it to my imageview.
I know to use alarm manager , but I do not know how to use it.

here I just selected my random id like this ans set to SharedPreferences and finally it get it.
i want to this every 24 hours.
would you please help?
I am new with android.

```
 private void setBG(int bg) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor share1 = getSharedPreferences("share1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    share1.putInt("bg", bg);
    share1.commit();
}

private int getBG() {
    SharedPreferences share1 = getSharedPreferences("share1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return share1.getInt("bg", R.drawable.pg19);
}

private void showBGS() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rndInt = rand.nextInt(18) + 1;
    String drawableName = "pg"+ rndInt;

    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
    setBG(resID);

}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with any Android-specific things. But if you only need to pull the randomly-selected image every so often (and never need to push it to somewhere, like for a notification or something), one option is to re-generate the random image based on the midnight timestamp, every time you need it. Something like `new Random(midnightTime).nextInt(numberOfImages)`.

Comment: what is midnight time? it must be somthing to check the hours

Comment: You would just get the current time, set the hours/minutes/seconds to 0 (in whatever datetime library you use), and then use the millis from that time.